# IntelliJ Idea 11 - How to expand Tomcat Server Stacktrace

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat7

While debugging Java EE applications, I can't see full stacktrace I see just a generic exception log; I'm looking details from Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug.

How can I see full stacktrace at Debugger panel of IntelliJ Idea 11?

Comment: Your question is about Tomcat and JavaEE, but mentioning Firebug and Chrome Developer tools is confusing. Please clarify what stacktrace you are looking for? If it's Java stacktrace, then why do you mention JavaScript specific tools? If it's JavaScript, then why JavaEE and Tomcat?

Comment: Because I handle client-server communication with AJAX requests. So I look **Network** tab of these tools.

Comment: Please correct the question to specify what stacktrace you are looking for, Java or JavaScript.

Comment: I'm looking for Java stacktrace within IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if exception is logged in any of the Tomcat log files. Note that IDEA runs Tomcat with modified CATALINA_BASE, so you should look for the logs under `%SYSTEM%\tomcat\tomcat_SEMIRANDOM_PART\logs\` directory, where `%SYSTEM%` is IDEA system directory which [depends on OS and IDEA version](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181).

If you see your exception logged there, configure this log file in IDEA Run configuration, [Logs tab](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/setting-log-options.html). You'll see a separate tab in IDEA with the contents of the configured server log.

If it's not logged there, you need to [adjust the default logging](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging) of your Tomcat server or your web application. The latter would depend on the specific logging framework.

If your app is using customized logging it's very possible that the default logging pattern doesn't include full stacktraces. It's also possible that your app doesn't log the exception completely, just the error text. In this case you will need to change the code of your application so that it logs the exception stacktrace.

Comment: OK thanks CrazyCoder, also there's a select option at **Tomcat Log** tab to show **all logs**.

Comment: On OSX Tomcat logs are located in ~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea12/tomcat/Unnamed_server/logs